# Collection stacks isEmpty method

Tags: java

learning about collection stacks, hopefully this is enough information, but essentially it keeps giving me an error.this error is also being shown when I use my pop method but showing peek should suffice.
The errors are

```
Exception in thread "main" McCracken_A06Q1$EmptyCollectionException: 
The stack is empty.
```

And

```
throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");
```

and errors where I put peek or pop methods in my main.

```
    public T peek() throws EmptyCollectionException {
        if (isEmpty()) 
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");


            return stack[top - 1];

    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this stack is empty and false otherwise.
     * 
     * @return true if this stack is empty
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (top >0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I assumed that it was my public static class EmptyCollectionException but I'm not getting any errors

```
public static class EmptyCollectionException extends RuntimeException {
    /**
     * Sets up this exception with an appropriate message.
     * 
     * @param collection
     *            the name of the collection
     */
    public EmptyCollectionException(String collection) {
        super("The " + collection + " is empty.");
    }
}
```

EDIT: for reference.. This is my main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayStack stack = new ArrayStack();

```
    System.out.println("STACK TESTING");

    stack.push(3);
    stack.push(7);
    stack.push(4);
    System.out.println(stack.peek());
    stack.pop();
    stack.push(9);
    stack.push(8);
    System.out.println(stack.peek());
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
    System.out.println(stack.peek());
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
    System.out.println(stack.pop());

    System.out.println("The size of the stack is: " + stack.size());
    System.out.println("The stack contains:\n" + stack.toString());
}
```

Comment: your question isn't clear. Are you getting an exception or not?

Comment: Maybe you update `top` incorrectly?

Comment: From what context are you trying to call the `peek()` method? If you try to call `peek()` on an empty stack, it of course is going to complain that the stack is empty.

Comment: It should be updating,  when I use push() then a pop or peek method it works fine. It just gives error when I  try to do an exception

Comment: sorry @gumbo, I updated to show my main method

Comment: @twokdavey And which line does the exception happen in? Or does it happen every time you try to use `pop()` or `peek()`? If that is the case, you probably did not update `top` correctly as @dejvuth pointed out. 
Also, maybe adding curly braces to your `if(isEmpty())` might be a good idea.

Comment: Three calls to `push()` => size 3. One call to `pop()` => size 2. Two calls to `push()` => size 4. **Five** calls to `pop()` => exception. Which part of this is confusing you?

Comment: everything works except exception portion. That is my whole point of the question @Andreas

Comment: Is the problem that is does throw an exception, but it shouldn't, or that it doesn't throw an exception, but it should?

Comment: @dutchen18 my code terminates when the exception attempts to be executed, exception fails.

Comment: @twokdavey I'm currently installing eclipse so i can confirm this, but i think the program SHOULD terminate when an uncaught RuntimeException is thrown.

Comment: @twokdavey You call `pop()` too many times, as I explained in previous comment, and calling `pop()` on an empty stack is *supposed* to throw an exception, and your question text and latest comment both indicate that are *are* getting the exception you're *supposed* to get, so what exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `pop` too many times throws an uncaught runtime exception, which terminates your program.

Try the following code:

```
try {
    // Stack operations that might throw an EmptyCollectionException go here
} catch (EmptyCollectionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // Handle exception here
}
```

Comment: OP is already getting a stacktrace, so what's the point of that? You might want to give more context to clarify.

Comment: @Andreas, twokdavey commented "my code terminates when the exception attempts to be executed, exception fails.".
The problem is that the code terminates because the exception is uncaught. If you catch the exception you can still print the stacktrace but the code won't terminate.

Comment: My point was that if you put *all* the code that's inside `main()` where you say `// Code goes here`, the result will be the same. You get a stacktrace and the program ends.

Comment: @Andreas this better?

Comment: Better, yes. But, OP *seems* to be complaining about the fact that an error occurs at all, not about the fact that the program ends when it happens. Of course, the question is a bit unclear: *"it keeps giving me an error"* but then saying *"I'm not getting any errors"*

Comment: @Andreas i'll have to disagree with you there, i think the OP is complaining about the program ending, and if that is the case this answer should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I count 5 `push`es and 6 `pop`s.  Therefore your exception is valid (assuming it's on the last `pop`).

Comment: Nice recap of [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602803/collection-stacks-isempty-method/39603716?noredirect=1#comment66514775_39602803), to which OP said *"everything works except exception portion. That is my whole point of the question"*, which of course just ends up making the entire question even less clear than it was to begin with. So, I'm not sure you're answering anything here. We're still trying to decipher what the question/problem is.